# React module federation issue with version 17 and 18

Tags: reactjs, webpack-module-federation

Below are the project details

app1 (remote) - react 18, webpack 5

app2 (host) - react 17, webpack 5

I am exposing the entire app1 to host and getting the below error (the error is pointing to browseRouter)
[image]

webpack config for app1

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin(
            {
                name: 'app1',
                filename: 'app1.js',
                library: { type: 'var', name: 'app1' },
                exposes: {
                    './app1': path.resolve(__dirname,'./src/module.tsx'),
                    './newReact': 'react',
                    './newReactDOM': 'react-dom',
                },
                shared: {
                    react: {
                        import: 'react', // the "react" package will be used a provided and fallback module
                        shareKey: 'newReact', // under this name the shared module will be placed in the share scope
                        shareScope: 'default', // share scope with this name will be used
                        singleton: true,
                        requiredVersion:'^18.2.0'
                        },
                    'react-dom':{requiredVersion:'^18.2.0',singleton:true},
                    '@reduxjs/toolkit': { singleton: true, requiredVersion:'^1.9,5'},
                    'react-router-dom': { singleton: true, requiredVersion:'^6.0.1' },
                    'react-redux':{singleton:true}
                }
            }
        )
```

webpack config for app2

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin(
      {
        name: 'app2',
        shared: {
                    react: { singleton: true, eager:true, requiredVersion:deps['react'] },
          'react-dom': {
            import: 'react-dom', // the "react" package will be used a provided and fallback module
            shareKey: 'react-dom', // under this name the shared module will be placed in the share scope
            shareScope: 'legacy', // share scope with this name will be used
            singleton: true,
            eager:true // only a single version of the shared module is allowed
          },
          '@reduxjs/toolkit': { singleton: true,eager:true, requiredVersion:deps['@reduxjs/toolkit'] },
                    'react-router-dom': { singleton: true,eager:true, requiredVersion:deps['react-router-dom'] },
                    'react-redux':{singleton:true},
           reactNew: {
            import: "react", // the "react" package will be used a provided and fallback module
            shareKey: "reactNew", // under this name the shared module will be placed in the share scope
            shareScope: "modern", // share scope with this name will be used
            singleton: true, // only a single version of the shared module is allowed
          }
                },
        remotes: {,
          "app1": "app1@[window.APP1_UI_URL]"

        },
      },
    )
```

took the reference from below repo
https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/different-react-versions-16-18-typescript

Could someone please help me on this?